# How to load all the results on a web page using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, click

I want to load all the games from the below web site.

http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2015-2016/results/

First load of the page shows me only a part of the total results, but I want to load all the data from the page.

Even if I use the below code to press the link "Show more matches", there are still hidden games not showed.

Could anyone help me with some hints?

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ0ud.png)

My code is below:

```
Sub Test_Flashscore()

Dim URL As String
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim dictObj As Object: Set dictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim tRowID As String

URL = "http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2015-2016/results/"

With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = True
    .navigate URL
    Do: DoEvents: Loop While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    Do: DoEvents: Loop While .document.readyState <> "complete"
    .document.parentWindow.execScript "loadMoreGames();"
    Do: DoEvents: Loop While .document.getElementById("preload").Style.display = "none"
End With


Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly, does it have to be that site or are other feeds worth considering?

Maybe: http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php 
so: 
http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/E0.csv

Comment: Using the DevTools (F12), when you click "Show more matches" I see a XHR requests.  

The first time to:
http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/tr_1_198_dYlOSQOD_165_1_0_en_1
Then
http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/tr_1_198_dYlOSQOD_165_2_0_en_1

Note the sequence.

The response seems obfuscated which I'm sure isn't too difficult to understand. For example the timestamps for the games are in Unix Epoch.

You can't just visit these URLs without providing an additional header, i.e.  X-Fsign. At the time of writing the request header needed to be:
X-Fsign:SW9D1eZo